# javafx 3d without scene graph

Tags: math, 3d, javafx

I have written my own routines for manipulating vectors and matrices including a number of math utilities.

I'd far rather use JavaFX without its scene graph and use my own routines, is it possible to manipulate just a single (4x4) matrix for each Shape3D you wish to render?

Comment: I suspect that "without its scene graph" is not what you really mean. The scene graph determines what is displayed, so without a scene graph you would not be able to see anything. Are you looking for something like a [`Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) or even [`WritableImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html)?

Comment: Thanks for reading the headline and not the actual body...

Comment: Your question title is "javafx 3d without scene graph", and all your actual question says is that you have written some linear algebra routines and want to "use JavaFX without its scene graph". I interpreted the rest as you wanting to somehow do direct rendering via your linear algebra routines. Nowhere did you say you wanted to put a Shape3D in the scene graph and then apply a transform to it, which is what you do in your answer.

Comment: " is it possible to manipulate just a single (4x4) matrix for each Shape3D you wish to render? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to Transform a Node directly rather than making it a child of a scene graph of transforms (for example and X,Y,Z axis rotation and a translation etc) you can use a single Affine matrix to do all the transformations (orientation/translation)

For example parent a Shape3D to this class then parent the Pivot to the root of the scene

```
package uk.co.bedroomcoders.jfx3dedit;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.transform.Affine;
import javafx.scene.transform.MatrixType;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Vec3d;

public class Pivot extends Group {

    private final double[] idt={1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1};

    public double rx,ry,rz;
    public Affine matrix=new Affine(idt,MatrixType.MT_3D_4x4,0);


    public Pivot() {
        super();
        getTransforms().setAll(matrix);
    }

    public Pivot(double x, double y, double z) {
        this();
        matrix.setTx(x);
        matrix.setTy(y);
        matrix.setTz(z);
    }

    public void setPosition(double x, double y, double z) {
        matrix.setTx(x);
        matrix.setTy(y);
        matrix.setTz(z);
    }

    public Vec3d getPosition() {
        return new Vec3d(matrix.getTx(),matrix.getTy(),matrix.getTz());
    }

    // set to eular rotation retaining translation (TODO reimplement fromQuat)
    public void updateFromEular(double rx, double ry, double rz) {
        double cx = Math.cos(rx);
        double cy = Math.cos(ry);
        double cz = Math.cos(rz);
        double sx = Math.sin(rx);
        double sy = Math.sin(ry);
        double sz = Math.sin(rz);
        matrix.setMxx(cy*cz);   matrix.setMxy((sx * sy * cz) + (cx * sz));      matrix.setMxz(-(cx * sy * cz) + (sx * sz));
        matrix.setMyx(-cy*sz);  matrix.setMyy(-(sx * sy * sz) + (cx * cz));     matrix.setMyz((cx * sy * sz) + (sx * cz));
        matrix.setMzx(sy);         matrix.setMzy(-sx*cy);                       matrix.setMzz(cx*cy);
    }

    // make this pivot face the a point
    public void lookAt(Vec3d centre, Vec3d up) {

        final Vec3d f = new Vec3d(), s = new Vec3d(), u = new Vec3d();
        final Vec3d t = new Vec3d(), eye = new Vec3d();

        eye.set(matrix.getTx(),matrix.getTy(),matrix.getTz());

        f.set(centre);
        f.sub(eye);
        f.normalize();

        up.normalize();

        t.set(f);
        s.cross(t,up);
        s.normalize();

        t.set(s);
        u.cross(t,f);
        u.normalize();

        matrix.setMxx( s.x);    matrix.setMxy( u.x);    matrix.setMxz( f.x);
        matrix.setMyx( s.y);    matrix.setMyy( u.y);    matrix.setMyz( f.y);
        matrix.setMzx( s.z);    matrix.setMzy( u.z);    matrix.setMzz( f.z);
    }

}
```